# Creating an empty response with status - is it possible? (Angular 2/4)

Tags: angular, angular-http

tell me, is it possible?

I need to create an empty response and initialize it. But the object is not initialized. What am I doing wrong?

```
    var options= new ResponseOptions({
      status: 201,
      url: CaSettings.API_HOME_SIGNUP_CONFIRM
    })
    var emptyResponse = new Response({init: options});
```

Thanks.

Comment: I used to do this : `let res = new Response(new ResponseOptions({body: JSON.stringify({item: 'value'})}))`

Comment: See https://angular.io/api/http/Response. The constructor of Response expects a ResponseOptions. Not an object with a key init of type ResponseOptions.

Comment: It does not work. Perhaps this works for content, but for status and url - no. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @JBNizet I have seen the documentation, so, too, does not work.
    var options = new ResponseOptions({
      status: 201,
      url: CaSettings.API_HOME_SIGNUP_CONFIRM
    });
    var emptyResponse = new Response(options);

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/0syIz2q7MvFJpHskAlxq?p=preview

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, everything works. I found a mistake in myself. The Response was not imported. )))  But I noticed this only in the sample code. Thank you, the question is solved.